# Number of possible ways for a person to reach from 1 to n

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose a person can dash to any position greater than her current
position without taking a break. In how many ways can the person reach
position n? For example, one possible way for the person is to directly dash
from 1 to n. Another way is to dash from 1 to 2, then 2 to 3, and
so on, until reaching n − 1 and finally n, taking a break and sending
photos between each dash.

If my answer is $2^{n-2}$ instead, is that right?
For example, from 1 to 4, the person would have 4 choices:
(1,2,3,4), (1,4), (1,2,4), (1,3,4)

Comment: You should have noticed that your formula fails when $n=2$.

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning that led to your (incorrect) answer?

Comment: @MJD It depends whether the start point is $0$ or $1$ - I think the question needs to make that absolutely specific, as it might be the point at issue. And also an explanation of the logic arriving at the suggested answer would be handy.

Comment: Choosing a route consists of choosing whether to stop at each possible stopping location. How many such locations are there?

Comment: @MarkBennet the examples given make clear that the start point is $1$.

Comment: How about 2^(n-2)? My reasoning is that, for example, from 1 to 4, the person could have 4 choices, (1,4), (1,2,3,4), (1,2,4), (1,3,4).

Comment: Hi: you have (n-2) numbers ( the first and last are fixed ) and you want to step through them and either pick that number or not pick it. So, my feeling is that $2^{(n-2)}$ is correct. It's like flipping a coin (n-2) times and counting the number of different sequences one can generate.

Comment: In the example of 4445se, the choices are (2,3). So the total number of sequences are (0,3) ,(0,0), (2,0) and (2,3) where a zero denotes "don't put it there".

Comment: @MJD The answer given was true if the starting point was zero, so I thought it worth checking.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I think you are right and your comment was well-considered.  Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are looking for a number of subsets $A\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $1\in A$ and $n\in A$. Which is of course in one-to-one correspondence with the number of subsets of $\{2,\ldots,n-1\}$ which finally indeed is equal to $2^{n-2}$.